# sed substitution including newlines

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I want to change a text file so that any line beginning with "Length:" is appended to the *previous* line.

I'm aware that `sed '/\nLength:/ Length:/'` isn't going to work because `sed` is line based.

Googling for "How to match newlines in sed" did turn up a complex sed method for joining a pattern to the *next* line but I couldn't figure out how to adapt it.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk` you can use something like:

```
awk '/^/&&!/^Length/{printf "\n"}{printf "%s",$0}' infile
```

Will only print `\n` when line start `^` is matched. Exception:  `Length` is found at that beginnig.

Comment: I would personally prefer to change the `printf "\n"` to `print ""` (but that's just a style thing). However, you should use a format specifier with `printf` like `printf "%s", $0`, to avoid characters on the line from being interpreted.

Comment: I agree , with the formatter should be more clear @TomFenech

Comment: Another minor thing - `printf` is not a function, so you don't need the parentheses (in fact some prefer to avoid them). Otherwise, looks good!

Answer (score 2):

If the file isn't too large, you can use a Perl command line in slurp mode (load all the file content before processing) :

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\R(?=Length:)//g' file
```

`-0777` switches on the slurp mode

pattern:

`\R` any kind of newlines

`(?=...)` lookahead assertion

If there's no consecutive lines starting with `Length:` you can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -n ':a;/\nLength:/!{$p;N;ba;}; s/\n\(Length:\)/$1/;p;' file
```

details:

```
:a;                  # define the label "a"
/\nLength:/! {       # if "\nLength:" doesn't match then:
    $p;              # if last line, print
    N;               # append the next line to the pattern space
    ba;              # go to label "a"
};
s/\n\(Length:\)/$1/; # perform the replacement
p;                   # print
```

An other way with awk using the record separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\nLength:";ORS="Length:"}1' file | head -n -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples and the descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\nLength:/s/\n/ /;P;D' file
```

This appends the next line to the present line in the pattern space and if the appended line begins with the required string it replaces the newline with a space (if you do not want the space just replace the newline with nothing). The first line is then printed and deleted and the process repeated (the second line is now the first unless the condition was met in which case a line is automatically read in and then the first command appends the next).